# Kohana 3.14 fails at unit testing with message class 'Kohana' not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, kohana, kohana-3, spl-autoload-register

I have a kohana website that works okay, and I started unit testing (retrospectively, I know it is not the best practice)

The first error I get and I cannot get rid of is quite puzzling:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Passed
>   array does not specify an existing static method (class 'Kohana' not
>   found)' in /Users/dananicula/Sites/mnib1/application/bootstrap.php:44

in bootstrap, line 44 is:

```
 spl_autoload_register(array('Kohana', 'auto_load'));
```

and class Kohana actualy exists in system/classes/kohana.php

Any hints? Opinions? Suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have your own unittests without loading Kohana core class. Use native [Unittest](https://github.com/kohana/unittest) module as described [here](http://blog.lysender.com/2011/02/kohana-3-1-migration-unit-testing/).